# I can't change a style through :hover using only CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a paragraph and a  tag inside it. When I hover paragraph is easy to change the color of the  tag:

```
<p>This is a <span>paragraph</span></p>

p:hover span{color:blue;}
```

I am trying to do the same with a Vertical Navigation Bar but it isn't working:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  background-color: red;
}

.primero:hover .changeColor {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="" class="primero">Google
    <a href="" class="changeColor">Coche</a>
  <a href="" class="changeColor">Avion</a>
  <a href="" class="changeColor">Bici</a>
  </a>
</nav>
```

The bottom three links do not change their color to blue when you mouse over the first link.

Why??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML is invalid. An `<a>` element cannot contain another `<a>` element.

The browser's error recovery logic means that in the DOM, the elements which are members of the `changeColor` class are not descendants of the element that is a member of the `primero` class.

You can see this using a DOM inspector:

[image: Screenshot demonstrating the above]

Consequently the descendant combinator in your CSS doesn't apply.

Write [valid](https://validator.nu/) HTML. Then worry about styling it.